# How to get ApplicationContext inside a unit test class of non-spring managed class

Tags: spring, mocking, mockito, powermock, spring-test

I have a requirement where I had to use Spring beans inside a POJO class to retrieve a MyDomainClass object. Since Autowiring the beans inside the class which is not managed by Spring isn't possible, I had to explicitly get the ApplicationContext from another util class and retrieve the bean from applicationContext object. Please find the code below

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware{
    
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

      @Override
      public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext)
          throws BeansException {
        applicationContext = appContext;
      }

      public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
      }
}
```

The code for using the applicationContext and retrieving the bean is below

```
public class MyNonBeanClass{

    public MyDomainClass retrieveMyDomainObj(){
        ApplicationContext applicationContext=ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext();
        TestBean testBean=(TestBean)applicationContext.getBean("testBean");
        return testBean.retrieve(param1,param2);
    }
    
}
```

This code is working as expected and I am able to fetch the beans from the application context successfully. But writing the test case has been challenging to say the least. I am not even sure if we will be able to write the test case for my non bean class but I would still like to try. I am trying to use PowerMock to mock the static invocation of getApplicationContext() in ApplicationContextUtils. But I am unable to get the applicationContext necessary for getting the TestBean object. And a NullPointerException is thrown when the getBean() is called on applicationContext. Please help with this.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ApplicationContextUtils.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= { BaseTestContext.class})
public class MyNonBeanClassTest implements ApplicationContextAware{
    
    MyNonBeanClass myNonBeanClass;
    
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
    @Test
    public void test_retrieveMyDomainObj(){
        myNonBeanClass=new MyNonBeanClass();
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ApplicationContextUtils.class);
        when(ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(applicationContext);
        assertNotNull(myNonBeanClass.retrieveMyDomainObj(param1, param2));
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext) throws BeansException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.applicationContext=appContext;
    }
    
    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(){
        return this.applicationContext;
    }
    
}
```